# What is purpose of having more than 1 signer for Android Apksigner signature Scheme V2

Tags: android, apksigner

Android Apksigner mentions that signature Scheme V2 supports multiple signers. 
I would like to know what is the purpose of having 2 signers because of my following concerns.

1. When using `jarsigner` to sign Android APKs, we could sign using more than one keys in different iterations and both the signature we kept in the apk.  In the case of `apksigner` when you sign with 2nd signature, it replaces 1st one. So if you want to sign using multiple signers then you will have to provide both the signers in the same command.
2. Private keys of the different signers will be with different persons, so when signing with `jarsigner`, it doesn't matter where the keys are. You share the apk with the signers and they will do their part. But for `apksigner` with multiple signers, you need to provide all the signers in a single command, but no one can share their private keys with others for signing on their behalf.

So I would like to know what is the purpose of having support for multiple signers? And how can we achieve what `jarsigner` did using Apksigner?

Comment: There's no such support in apksigner today. Note also that Play Console does not support multiple signers (they do support chain of certificates though).

Comment: Note also that in APK signature scheme v3, support for multiple signers has been dropped (support for key rotation has been added instead).